# Why am I not receiving data from my device (microcontroller) when I send stuff?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port, microcontroller, send

I wrote a simple Serial Port send-receive c# program. I am able to send stuff to the device (microcontroller) however, i do not receive any data back from the controller. The device is definitely working because I used 2 different programs (Realterm & Hyperterminal) to send stuff and I am receiving the back data just fine. Also, I tested my code to make sure there wasnt anything wrong with it and it worked fine as well. (Tested it by connecting it pc to pc via serial port connection and sent/receive data). I have tried different things to fix this issue but i cannot seem to find the solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
namespace SMCData
{ 

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataRecivedHandler);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            comport.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }

    // settup connection 
    void setport()
    {
        //checking if Baud_Rate_txt is blank
        string temp1 = Baud_Rate_txt.Text;

        if (temp1 == "")
        {
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        }
        else
        {
            _serialPort.BaudRate = int.Parse(Baud_Rate_txt.Text);
        }


        /* if (comport.SelectedIndex == -1)
         {
            ErrorBox.Text = " Need Com Port name";
             return;
         } */
        _serialPort.PortName = comport.Text;//comport.SelectedItem.ToString();
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
        switch (HandshakeCB.Text)
        {
            case "None":
                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                break;
            case "XOnXOff":
                _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
                _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
                break;
        }
        switch (Parity_CB.Text)
        {
            case "None":
                _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                break;
            case "Even":
                _serialPort.Parity = Parity.Even;
                break;
            case "Odd":
                _serialPort.Parity = Parity.Odd;
                break;
        }
        // Looks for user input on the desired Stop Bits of Application
        switch (StopBitsCB.Text)
        {
            case "1":
                _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                break;
            case "2":
                _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
                break;
            case "None":
                _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.None;
                break;
        }
        try
        {
            _serialPort.Open();


        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            errorbox.Text = ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }

    }

    private void DataRecivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
         int temp2;
     int temp =sp.BytesToRead;
     byte[] array = new byte[temp];
     temp2 = sp.Read(array, 0, temp);
          if (this.DataRecived.InvokeRequired) 
          {
              DataRecived.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                  {
                      DataRecived.Text = DataRecived.Text + Encoding.Default.GetString(array) + System.Environment.NewLine;

                  }));
          }

    }

      private void sendBLN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        byte[] array_out = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SendTXT.Text);
        string command = "myCommand";

        _serialPort.Write(array_out, 0, array_out.Length);

        byte[] array_out2 = new byte[1];
        array_out2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r");

        _serialPort.Write(array_out2, 0, array_out2.Length);
        // _serialPort.Write(string.Format("{0}\r", command));

        // _serialPort.Write(array_out2, 0, array_out2.Length);
        //_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 13, 10 }, 0, 2);

    }

    private void Refresh_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
          {
              comport.Items.Remove(s);
          }

          foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
          {
              comport.Items.Add(s);
          }
      }

      private void Connectbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          try
        {
            if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
                errorbox.Text = errorbox.Text + "Connected..." + System.Environment.NewLine;
            setport();

        }
          catch (Exception ex )
          {
            errorbox.Text = errorbox.Text + ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
      }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _serialPort.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRecived.Text = " ";
        errorbox.Text = " ";

    }

    private void DataRecived_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        byte[] array_out2 = new byte[1];
        array_out2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r");

        _serialPort.Write(array_out2, 0, array_out2.Length);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: How all did you try to debug this? I am sure you might have checked few of these, but still. Did you make sure the baud rate and the start/stop/parity bits match? Did you try to debug on controller to see if its atleast receiving the message? try putting a scope or analyser on it?

Comment: At first I thought `DataRecived` was a typo

Comment: I've never used `SerialPort`, but is it possible that `_serialPort.DataReceived` is firing on the GUI thread?  Because if so, the text won't get updated in `DataRecivedHandler`: you handle the case where `InvokeRequired` is true but not the case where it's false.